# I am learning about null hypothesis and statistical inference. A problem was presented to me, I wrote the code but it seems I overlooked something:

Tags: r, for-loop, random, statistics

```
library(downloader) 
url <-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/femaleControlsPopulation.csv"
filename <- basename(url)
download(url, destfile=filename)
x <- unlist( read.csv(filename) )
head(x)
```

**Problem at hand:**
Set the seed at 1, then using a for-loop take a random sample of 5 mice 1,000 times. Save these averages.

What proportion of these 1,000 averages are more than 1 gram away from the average of x ?

**My script:**

```
set.seed(1)
weightsample<-vector("numeric", 1000)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  random<-sample(x, 5) 
  weightsample[i]<-mean(random)
  }

popmean<-mean(x)
mean(abs(weightsample - popmean)>1)

my erroneous answer:
 0.498
```

Comment: What is `x`? It is not defined. You only test for one gram larger. What about 1 gram smaller?

Comment: x is a numerical vector of length 225, it contains mice weights in grams. I tried the absolute values ***mean(abs(weightsample)>abs(popmean+1))*** and it gives me the same answer.

Comment: I guess you might need to try `mean(abs(weightsample - popmean)>1)`

Comment: so I tried what you suggested #ThomasIsCoding, it gave me a different answer (0.4976). It's still wrong though.

Comment: If both values 0.265 in the OP and 0.4976 in the comment is wrong, what is the right value (or the value you expect to be)? Are you sure you are expecting correctly?

Comment: I get 0.232 from your code and 0.503 from @ThomasIsCoding's comment on my machine. Both values differ from yours.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704, did you change the script in any way? If the seed is set to 1 we should be getting the same samples.    I don't know the correct answer, I just have to input my answer into a platform.

Comment: No. That's why I point this out. I copy-paste your code and just run it in fresh R session. By the way, theoretically the result from @ThomasIsCoding's code answers your question "What proportion of these 1,000 averages are more than 1 gram away from the average of x ?" That is, if you don't expect certain correct value to appear.

Comment: I tried 0.503 and that's the answer. Would my version of R affect my answer in any way?

Comment: it should not. are you setting the same seed every time you run the for loop? then using thomas's code?

Comment: Yes, I'm still not getting the same answer. I have no clue what it could be if the script is correct.